Condition for $\int_a^b \tan (x) \, dx=\log (\cos (a))-\log (\cos (b))$ to be valid
The indefinite integral is given by:
$$\int \tan (x) \, dx=-\log (\cos (x))$$
and I am trying to determine the conditions on $a$ and $b$ (can be real or complex) under which the definite integral  is valid (path is the straight line joining $a$ and $b$):
$$\int_a^b \tan (x) \, dx=\log (\cos (a))-\log (\cos (b))$$
For example, if $a$ and $b$ are real, the integral will diverge when there is a singular point lying between $a$ and $b$. Similarly, for complex $a$ and $b$, if $\cos(t)$ where $t$ goes from $a$ to $b$, crosses the branch cut of $\log(x)$ (negative real axis), the above integral won't be valid (by $log$ here I denote the principal branch of the logarithm).
Below I am providing some example $(a, b)$ pairs for which the integral is valid or not valid:
Integral is valid:
$(-\frac{\pi }{4},\frac{\pi }{4}), (\frac{\pi }{8}+i,\frac{\pi }{4}-2 i), (-i,2 i), (i+\frac{11 \pi }{4},-i+\frac{13 \pi }{4}), (i+\pi ,i+\frac{3 \pi }{2})$
Integral is not valid:
$(0,\pi ), (i+\frac{5 \pi }{2},\frac{11 \pi }{4}),(i+\frac{11 \pi }{4},i+\frac{13 \pi }{4}),(\frac{\pi }{2},i),(\frac{3 \pi }{4},i+\frac{3 \pi }{4})$
I would like to find the necessary and sufficient (complete) condition. I tried using CAS and looking around for materials, but could not find a satisfactory answer.
I need the condition in a mathematical form involving $a$ and $b$ in which I can plug in values and check whether the integral is valid or not for particular values of $a$ and $b$.
I have made some progress especially when $a$ and $b$ are real, and will post it as a partial answer in 1-2 days. However my procedure is quite laborious and I am also not sure about the accuracy. So if someone can present an intelligent technique to determine the condition accurately that would help.
Thanks in advance.

For complex numbers $a, b$ the notation $\int_a^b f(z) dz$ is ambiguous because it depends on which integration path is chosen. That notation is only used if the integral does not depend on the path, i.e. for function holomorphic in a simply-connected domain.

@MartinR, fair enough. I have updated the post and mentioned that the integration path is the straight line joining a and b.

Whenever $\cos(t) \ne 0$ on the straight line from $a$ to $b$ there is some holomorphic branch of $\log(\cos(t))$ in a small (simply-connected) neighborhood of that line, and the formula holds with that branch of the logarithm.

By $log$ in the integral, I intend to denote the principal branch of logarithm. This way the formula remains consistent and easier to handle. Mentioning it in the post.

Well, then the formula should be valid whenever $\cos(t)$ does not cross the negative real axis.

If $\cos (t)$ crosses the negative real axis even number times in opposite directions, then also the formula remains valid. Example: $a=\frac{\pi }{8}+i, b=2 \pi -2 i$

I will post an answer based on my research so far. The condition is not complete. There are points which does not satisfy my condition yet still ensures the validity of the formula for the integral. If someone can suggest an alternate and better method for finding the complete condition, that would be helpful.
For the formula to be valid, we have to ensure that i. the line joining $a$ and $b$ does not cross any singular points of the integrand, $\tan (x)$ and the integral $-\log (\cos (x))$ and ii. as $x$ goes from $a$ to $b$, $\cos (x)$ does not cut the branch cut of $\log (z)$ which is the negative real axis.
We will develop the conditions for 5 cases and then combine the conditions.
The final condition should come with the guarantee that whatever ${a, b}$ pair satisfies it, must satisfy the original integral formula. However there can be other points ${a, b}$ which does not satisfy the condition but for which the integral formula is valid. Ideally I would like to find such a complete condition, and any help is appreciated.
Case 1:
First we consider the case when $\cos (a)$ and $\cos (b)$ are real.
$\cos (a)$ is real not only when $a$ is real, but at $\cosh (k-i \pi  n)$ where $n$ is an integer and $k$ is a real number
The condition is:
$$\cos (a)\in \mathbb{R}\land \cos (b)\in \mathbb{R}\land \cos (a) \cos (b)>0\land | \Re(a-b)| <\pi$$
Reasoning: $\cos (a)$ and $\cos (b)$ should be of the same sign. Otherwise we will have a point c between a and b for which $\cos (c)$ is 0 and thus we will end up crossing a singular point.
Case 2:
Next we consider the case when $\Re(a)$ and $\Re(b)$ are between two consecutive singular points (e.g. $-\frac{\pi }{2}$ and $\frac{\pi }{2}$) and $\cos (\Re(a))>0$ and $\cos (\Re(b))>0$. Let us check the graphs of the real and imaginary parts of $\cos (x)$:

The condition in this zone can be written as:
$$\cos (\Re(a))>0\land \cos (\Re(b))>0\land | \Re(a-b)| <\pi$$
Since the real part of $\cos (x)$ is always greater than 0 here, $\cos (x)$ will never cut the branch cut of $\log (z)$ (the branch cut is in the negative real line).
Case 3:
Next we consider the case when $\Re(a)$ and $\Re(b)$ are between two consecutive singular points (e.g. $\frac{\pi }{2}$ and $\frac{3 \pi }{2}$) and $\cos (\Re(a))<0$ and $\cos (\Re(b))<0$. Let us check the graphs of the real and imaginary parts of $\cos (x)$:

The condition in this zone can be written as:
$$\cos (\Re(a))<0\land \cos (\Re(b))<0\land | \Re(a-b)| <\pi \land \Im(\cos (a)) \Im(\cos (b))>0$$
The real part of $\cos (x)$ is always less than 0 here. From the graph of the imaginary part, it can be concluded that any two points for which $\Im(\cos (a))$ and $\Im(\cos (b))$ are of the same sign, the joining line will either not cross the branch cut or will cross it twice in opposite directions.
Case 4:
Finally we consider the case when $\cos (a)$ and $\cos (b)$ are purely imaginary.
The condition can be written as:
$$\Re(\cos (a))=0\land \Re(\cos (b))=0\land (| \Re(a-b)| =\pi \lor \Re(a-b)=0)\land \Im(\cos (a)) \Im(\cos (b))>0$$
$\Im(\cos (a))$ and $\Im(\cos (b))$ having the same sign ensures that we do not have $\Im(\cos (t))=0$ at a point t on the line joining $a$ and $b$. This will entail crossing a singular point. We keep the absolute value of $\Re(a-b)$ less than $\pi$, to ensure that $\cos (x)$ does not have enough room to come back to the imaginary line after crossing the branch cut.
Final condition:
Combining the conditions we get the final condition:
$$(\cos (a)\in \mathbb{R}\land \cos (b)\in \mathbb{R}\land \cos (a) \cos (b)>0\land | \Re(a-b)| <\pi )\lor (\cos (\Re(a))>0\land \cos (\Re(b))>0\land | \Re(a-b)| <\pi )\lor (\cos (\Re(a))<0\land \cos (\Re(b))<0\land | \Re(a-b)| <\pi \land \Im(\cos (a)) \Im(\cos (b))>0)\lor (\Re(\cos (a))=0\land \Re(\cos (b))=0\land (| \Re(a-b)| =\pi \lor \Re(a-b)=0)\land \Im(\cos (a)) \Im(\cos (b))>0)$$
